# Syntax Error/Two main programs Fortran

Tags: fortran, mingw

I'm trying to compile this program for monte carlo importance sampling, but i'm running into a couple issues:

1 - Error: Syntax error in data declaration at (1), referring to the following line, where the (1) is placed right after and beneath the word "function".

```
real function f(x)
```

2 - Error: Two main PROGRAMS at (1) and (2), referring to these two lines

```
program importance1
```

and

```
t=0.0
```

.

The sample code follows. There are more lines of code in the program, but I don't think there are any problems so I've just posted this first segment.

```
program importance1
implicit none
real mean_value,t,ta,rr
real x,xtrials,s_square_old,s_square_new,std_dev,std_error,frac_stand_dev
integer k
real :: alpha=0.90
integer :: trials=50
xtrials=trials

real function f(x)
f=exp(x)
return
end

real function g(x)
g=(alpha/(exp(alpha)-1.))*exp(alpha*x)
return
end

t=0.0
s_square_old=0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where you got the idea to do that, but it looks like you are defining functions in the middle of your code, which is the wrong place. In Fortran, the functions go in a separate `MODULE` or at the end of the program under a `CONTAINS` block:

```
program importance1
  implicit none
  real :: mean_value,t,ta,rr
  real :: x,xtrials,s_square_old,s_square_new,std_dev,std_error,frac_stand_dev
  integer :: k
  real :: alpha=0.90
  integer :: trials=50
  xtrials=trials

  t=0.0
  s_square_old=0.0

contains

  real function f(x)
    real :: x
    f=exp(x)
  end function

  real function g(x)
    real :: x
    g=(alpha/(exp(alpha)-1.))*exp(alpha*x)
  end function

end program
```

Comment: Functions and subroutines can also be placed above the `program` statement without `contains`.

Comment: True, nor is a module truly necessary. But using the module & contains will help the compiler catch errors in linking.

Comment: Yeah, definitely no excuse to not use modules nowadays.

Comment: That works, thank you very much. My professor gave some sample code but it didn't work as expected so I've just been messing around with it.